# accord de "enregistreurs numérique(s)"

Tags: vocabulaire, adjectifs, accord

Est-ce que *numérique* prend un "s" ? ça fait un peu comme dans la phrase :

> les samedis matin

Pour moi il n'y a qu'un numérique : soit on l'est, soit on ne l'est pas. Mais il n'y a pas plusieurs numérique(s). Le truc, sur Internet, je vois partout l'accord avec "s". Donc j'ai besoin que l'on m'éclaire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Numérique* est ici un adjectif, donc il s'accorde avec le nom. Un enregistreur numérique est enregistreur qui représente les données à l'aide d'un codage discret, en pratique binaire, qui peut être vu comme une suite de nombres, par opposition à un enregistreur analogique qui utilise des phénomènes physiques continus pour représenter les données.

Le mot *numérique* commence à être utilisé comme nom, dans le sens de l'aspect sociétal des moyens de calculs et de communication numériques, mais cela n'a rien à voir avec le sens dans « enregistreurs numériques ».

Comment: merci à toi gilles